# css to create rectangle with color and right arrow in the end

Tags: css

```css
.some_class {
    padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    margin: 1px; border: 1px solid grey;
    display: inline-block;
    }

.text-grey {
    background-color: grey;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin: 1px; width: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="..\html\index.html"><span class="some_class">HOME </span></a> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right text-grey" > </span> </li>

</ul>
```

How to create `CSS` to place text with partially filled with color and right arrow as shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbRLR.jpg)

Comment: This what i have tried so far <li><a href="..\html\index.html"><span>HOME </span></a> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right text-grey" > </span> </li>  and my css code :span {
    padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
    margin: 1px;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    display: inline-block;
}
.text-grey {

 background-color: grey;
 border: 1px solid grey;
 margin: 1px;
 width: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

Comment: You are starting on the right track, but you need to make sure to post your code in the question next time :)

Comment: For the arrow, you could use &rarr; - the UTF-8 right arrow.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a beginning:

```
.button {
  border: 1px solid blue
}
.button:after {
  display: block;
  background: url(arrow.png) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should help you get there. No need for the right arrow to be an image, since it could be a character.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
    background: black
}
ul, li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.some_class {
    font-family: monospace;
    border: 1px solid #00e5ee;
    color: #00e5ee; 
    background: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.some_class span {
    padding: 0px 12px;
}
.rightArrow {
    color: white !important;
    background: #00e5ee !important;
    padding: 0px 6px;
    font-weight: bold;  
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="..\html\index.html" class="some_class"><span>HOME</span><span class="rightArrow">&#8594;</span></a></span></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest I can suggest is using a pseudo element, like this

```css
body {
  background: black;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #099;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #099;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a::after {
  content: '\2192';
  font-size: 20px;
  background: #099;
  color: white;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 2px 10px 2px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li> <a href="..\html\index.html">HOME</a> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I thought about this but I heard somewhere that it was a bad idea to include UTF-8 characters without the HTML encoding (i.e. `&rarr;`) and the encoding doesn't seem to work in the pseudo-element, so I just used a `span`.

Comment: @SamMearns You use it like this when you want the encoding `\2192` ... updated my answer

Comment: This is the right answer. Looks like op is using bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to that is via css, using button:after {
content:'code';}. You can use fontawesome, or something similar(this is if you are using wordpress).
If you are making your own code than you can use either  or  or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, have fun (I'm commenting it up now to explain the code):

https://jsfiddle.net/MasterDoctor/rcc37dbr/1/

HTML:

```
<nav class="fancynav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="arrow-link">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="arrow-link">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  /* Set body background (duh!) */
  background-color: #000;
}

nav.fancynav ul {
  /* Style navbar list */
    list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav.fancynav ul li {
  /* Remove bullet points */
    list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

nav.fancynav ul li a {
  color: #3F51B5;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Verdana";
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  transition: border-bottom 0.15s;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

nav.fancynav ul li a:hover:not(.arrow-link) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #3F51B5;
}

nav.fancynav ul li a.arrow-link {
  /* Style the main link as a block, with uppercase letters, Verdana font, blue color, no margin or padding, some left and vertical padding and a nice CSS transition. */
  font-family: "Verdana";
  display: inline-block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #3F51B5;
  border: 1px solid #3F51B5; 
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 24px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition: background-color 0.15s, color 0.15s;
}

nav.fancynav ul li a.arrow-link:hover {
  /* Modify the color and background on hover */
  color: white;
  background-color: #3F51B5;
}

nav.fancynav ul li a.arrow-link:after {
  /* This is for styling the arrow, make it a block (but inline), the right background color, set the line height to make the arrow vertically centered, add some margin for spacing and finally set the color of the arrow. */
  content: "\2192";
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #3F51B5;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: white;
}
```

Edit #1: Sorry, I know posting completed code is frowned upon but I'm procrastinating on some nasty backend work (and homework).

Edit #2: For the triangles, you can use CSS (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/) or you can use UTF-8 symbols (https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_arrows.asp)